# Need the name of a small pin used as a cheap door hinge

Tags: hinges

What is the name of this pin?[image: this pin]
I have a cheap piece of furniture where two of these pins are used as hinges: one side goes in to the frame and one side goes in to the door. I lost one of the pins and I can't find the name of it to buy another one.

Answer (score 2):

If it's 5mm in diameter, it's a common shelf pin / shelf support.

Comment: I must say, I have never seen one with a shoulder and round on both ends, one end is usually slightly flattened.

Comment: Jack - Do an image search with Google using "Shelf Support Peg" as the search term. You will see just how many styles of these things there are. In the picture search results you will see quite a number of pegs that are almost identical to what @Poster has shown. Many of the pictures are from UK based auctions on eBay that are showing them as 5mm bright galvanised steel shelf pegs.

Comment: I did check, I knew there were a many, I did not want to go by my memory which is not the best. I thought about 30 years ago I seen that type of shelf pins used in a cabinet...

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the name of the pin, it is probably specific to the maker.

An easy replacement is a short steel dowel and a washer. Set the dowel in the hole add the washer, which is a spacer and set the door panel

Answer (score 0):

its a shelf pin.  you can get them here:

http://www.richelieu.com/ca/en/category/furniture-hardware/shelf-pins-latches-catches-bumpers/shelf-pins/metal-shelf-pin/duplo-metal-shelf-pin/1015309?s=shelf+pin

Answer (score -1):

Divided pin. They are used for shelf rests but also as inexpensive hinge pins.

Comment: A link or reference supporting the name would be useful.